# ManyToOne Multiple Join Columns, One is Default Value

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Class A has a composite primary key which is created using an Embeddable. In Class B, I reference Class A from a ManyToOne relationship. However, Class B only has one of the columns of the composite primary key from Class A. For the other value, I would like it to be a default value.

Is this possible?

I've tried using multiple join columns but that doesn't work because the second column doesn't exist anywhere in the table. I've also thought that maybe there is a solution that uses Transient but I'm not really sure how that would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If A has a composite primary key, then both parts are needed to uniquely identify As.  So your database really has a OneToMany from B->A where you want the entity to only reference a particular object based on a set value.  I don't think this is a great idea, as it will make entity reuse difficult, and inserting and manipulating As and Bs extremely complicated, and  JPA does not allow for it.  Using a single unique identifier like a sequence is usually preferable.

Hibernate and other providers do allow using partial keys in references.  You will need to add a Hibernate filter to the relationship to get it to pull out only 1 B based on the unmapped field: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html